# ASP.NET MVC Manage SQLConnection with Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orm, sqlconnection

I am giving the new Dapper Micro ORM released by Stack Overflow/Sam Saffron a quick go using MVC.  I'm wondering what is the simplest way to manage a SQLConnection object inside my controller?  I am doing something simple like this just to spin through some data and test out Dapper, but is it idea to be opening/closing the connection like so?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ajh"].ConnectionString);

    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // get me all comments
        conn.Open();
        var comments = conn.ExecuteMapperQuery<Comment>("select * from Comment");
        conn.Close();

        return View(comments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create, open and close the connection as locally as possible:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Comment> comments;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(/* ... */))
        {
            conn.Open();
            comments = conn.ExecuteMapperQuery<Comment>("select * from Comment");
        }
        return View(comments);
    }
}
```

Although it's best practice to avoid direct data-access in your controllers. Bury your data-access methods inside a `CommentsService` class or similar and call that from your controller.

Comment: Luke thanks for the answer. I'm just thinking for an extremely small CRUD application keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @aherrick: Fair enough, I'd probably do the same. If the code really is this simple then adding extra layers and abstractions often makes things worse, not better!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but of `var comments` is deferred in its execution, then you'll have a problem and will have to use something like .ToList to fully enumerate the results before closing the connection.  Otherwise, if `.ExecuteMapperQuery` fully enumerates the results before returning them you will be fine

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yeah it fully enumerates and returns a List of T.  I'm wondering more so is there a better/cleaner way to be managing my SQLConnection object and having to Open/Close the given connection every time.

Comment: @aherrick, just do it in a base controller, or external helper... you do not want to be opening and closing connections 50 times on a single page ... even with pooling this can get expensive

Comment: @SamSaffron is it ok if i open a connection in my controller and dispose it in Dispose method ?

Comment: @SamSaffron I'm little confused. Jon Skeet said that 'The best approach is almost always to create a new SqlConnection each time you need one - and dispose of it as soon as you're finished with it' in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925209/passing-sqlconnection-to-class-loses-its-connectionstring-after-dispose#26925209