# Passing SqlConnection to class loses its connectionstring after dispose

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have following simple class definition (a windows console application):

**SAMPLE as Expected**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    class Test: IDisposable {
        string Text;

        public Test(string str) {
            Text = str;
        }

        public void print() {
            Console.WriteLine("Text: " + Text);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Text = "";
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string TeXT = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;";

            using (Test test = new Test(TeXT)) {
                test.print();
            }

            using (Test test = new Test(TeXT)) {
                test.print();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

in above example I pass a `string` to a `IDisposable` class `test`. As soon as code goes out of scope it is disposed. As expected the local variable `TeXT` is not touched after disposing the test for the first time and it is accessible for second instance of test class the same way it was.

Now here is the real scenario that made me scratch my head for hours.

**Actual Result**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    class Test: IDisposable{
        SqlConnection dbConn;

        public Test(SqlConnection connection){
            dbConn = connection;
        }

        public void print(){
            Console.WriteLine("Connection" + dbConn.ConnectionString);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;");

            using(Test test = new Test(sqlConn)){
                test.print();
            }

            using(Test test = new Test(sqlConn)){
                test.print();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Same as before I pass a `SqlConnection` to first instance of `test` class. After disposing the first instance, `SqlConnection` looses the connection string. which makes it unavailable for next instance of class.

**Question**
Why in second case I lose ConnectionString? Is this a bug or intentional? Is there any solution to avoid this except making multiple connections to DB Server? should I stop disposing the internal connection instance?

**Note**
[SqlCommand-SqlConnection Using Disposing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783907/sqlcommand-sqlconnection-using-disposing-issue) does not answer my question

Comment: Don't try to share `SqlConnection`s around in your code - share the connection *string* but make anything that wants an actual connection create one when it needs it and dispose of it when it's done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're disposing of the `SqlConection` when you dispose of the `Test` - but you're then trying to use it again.

The best approach is almost *always* to create a new `SqlConnection` each time you need one - and dispose of it as soon as you're finished with it. You're already doing the second part, but you should create a new `SqlConnection` instance for the second operation.

Note that that *doesn't* mean making multiple connections to the server, necessarily - the .NET connection pool will handle how many actual network connections are needed.

Comment: I think the OP means, the `ConnectionString` `property` is cleared after calling `Dispose()`

Comment: Isn't sqlConn created outside scope of test? passing it to a subclass should not destroy it, unless I send reference, am I right? If the SqlConnection is disposed after first `using`, why I still can pass it to second `using` and still able to read its ConnectionString property (and other properties too, only ConnectionString is empty)?

Comment: as your `sqlConn` object is disposed you can't have access to any properties of it

Comment: @Bistro, Jon is right. you should always create a new `connection` whenever you needed.. Just store your `connectionstring` somewhere else and create connection using it

Comment: @leppie: Yes, it's slightly odd that the connection string is cleared - but if you follow the normal approach of creating a new `SqlConnection` each time, that won't be a problem at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I recently had to clean up this exact anti-pattern in our web codebase... Not sure how these silly ideas catch on.

Comment: I put some of original code in pastebin (as much as I could) http://pastebin.com/txzFL34t. I am allowed to have one single open connection to database as anytime. does .NET connection pool handle this? So as per your suggestion I have to create connection everytime I need one, wouldn't this slow down the connection to SQL server?

Comment: @Bistro: Ideally, you should get rid of the instance variable. What do you mean by "allowed" here? What's stopping you having more than one if you really need it? But no, this shouldn't slow anything down - the "real" connection will be reused by the pool.

Comment: I cannot have more than one connection to Database server at each time, second connection will be dropped by database server. One more question, if I don't use the same connection again, how I should handle transactions (`SqlTransaction`)?

Comment: @Bistro: It sounds like you just need to configure the pool to have a maximum size of 1 then. I can't remember how you do that offhand, but I'm sure it's possible in a config file. If you need to do multiple operations in one transaction, they *should* use a single `SqlConnection` - but you shouldn't dispose of that between operations.

Comment: Tq for your help. I believe your answer is the best I can get. I need to change my coding habits. By the way, it seems if the `Test` class is in different assembly than `Program` class (different dll), connection will not drop at end of `using` block, which makes stranger to me.

Comment: @Bistro: I strongly suspect you're misdiagnosing that, to be honest. Or you've got something else going on... But if you make the appropriate changes, it shouldn't matter :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why in second case I lose ConnectionString?

Because your two examples have very little in common.

In your first class's `Dispose()` method, you set `Text = "";`. This will alter the reference that your class holds, but not the reference from `Main()`, **nor its value**. So `TeXT` from `Main()` will still hold your connection string.

In your second example, you call `Dispose()` **on the same instance**, namely the `sqlConn` you pass from `Main()`.

When you `Dispose()` an object, this doesn't mean you can't call methods or access properties. What exactly a class does when you dispose it differs per type. For `SqlConnection`, it apparently sets its `ConnectionString` property to an empty string, among other things like returning the connection (if any) to the connection pool.

Comment: Both `string`s and `SqlConnection` objects are reference types and so in both cases (absent the `ref` or `out` keyword), *references* to the actual objects are passed by value.

Comment: Yes, it is. The key difference between them is that strings are designed to be *immutable*. But both `string` and `SqlConnection` are reference types, and for all reference types, the default behaviour is that the *references* are passed by value.

Comment: Again this is not the case. `SqlConn` is still available for second `using` (it is not disposed). only ConnectionString is deleted and Connection is closed (for obvious reason).

Comment: @CodeCaster, I just checked my working code. If I just set the connection string between two usings, I am good to go. it is even able to connect again (calling methods are available too) It seems somehow the object stays in memory for longer than end of first using.

Comment: @Bistro I'm not entirely sure what you're saying there, but `Dispose()` does nothing special to an object. It is just a method from an interface that allows the object to be used in a `using()` statement. It does not remove the object from memory or whatever.